# How to recive response from XMLHttpRequest by python?

Tags: python, post, xmlhttprequest, urllib2, urllib

How to recive response from XMLHttpRequest by python?

I use this:

```
data = (xml_string)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

but I only print the 'main page'.

Response open in another window in Chrome with format "data:text/xml,xml_sting_with_data") I try to get xml_sting_with_data by python

Comment: What do you mean by 'the responsive'? This page http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html tells you how to get the metadata about the response (eg the response code)

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a page that gets its data via XMLHttpRequests? urllib does not execute javascipt in a page.